# How to better deal with group by in data.table in this case?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have data like:

```
dt <- data.table(x=1:5, y=c(1,1,2,2,1), y.z=c(1,1,2,2,3))
```

And I like to group by per `y.z`. `dt` is constructed in a way that for each distinct `y.z` group, all values of `y` should be equal. The resulting data table I would like is sum of `x` , and the unique 1 value of `y` per group of 'y.z'

So, there are 2 approaches that meet my needs:

```
dt[,list(x=sum(x), y=y[1]), by=y.z]
dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=list(y.z, y)]
# it might have performance drawback, but I assume it is minor.
```

Due to my laziness, normally I would just opt to the 2nd way, cus it saves some typing if the list of y-like arguments is long. I.e. write `list(y.z, y1, y2, y3,...)` instead of `y1=y1[1], y2=y2[1], y3=y3[1], ...`

However, I am not very sure if this is a good practice. Especially if it happens that there is some errors in `y` so that it is not all equal for each group, my approach wouldn't trigger any error so the issue is not automatically detectable.

Is it best to customize a function like this?

```
 dt[,list(x=sum(x), y=assert.identical(y)]), by=y.z]
```

So if `y` contains only 1 unique value it returns a scalar, otherwise it can trigger an exception. However a customized function is a bit inconvenient to apply since it requires to type even more than `y=y[1]`.

I encounter this dilemma everyday, in R as well as in SQL, both have no cure. What do people normally do when they face it?

Answer (score 1):

`unique.data.table` has a `by` argument, and `.SD` is just a `data.table`.
Putting this together allows you to execute something like:

```
dt[,list(x= unique(.SD[, sum(x)], by=c("y1","y2", "y3")), by=y.z]
```

*Note that the `by` in unique must be a vector of strings (the names of the columns). This is different than the requirements for the `by` in `[.data.table` )*

Comment: how does it differ from `dt[,list(x=sum(x)), by=list(y.z, y)]?`